# CentOS no disk space left while copying a file to /home/ansible-user/ however admin-vol1 is of 100gb

Tags: linux, centos7

I am trying to copy a tarball to a server having CentOS 7 using winscp.
The copying after some time throws an error that no space left. However when I check from the monitoring GUI it shows that the server has a vol of 100gb. I am copying to the home/ansible-user user directory which has a space of only 2GB.

How can I increase the space allocated to the home/ansible-user folder?
Also Where is the 100gb space getting used up is not clear by the df or df -h how and where it is getting used up? Here is the output of the command

```
3.9G  1.3G  2.5G  34% /
485M     0  485M   0% /dev
496M     0  496M   0% /dev/shm
496M   51M  446M  11% /run
496M     0  496M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
496M  4.0K  496M   1% /tmp
99G   61M   94G   1% /data
488M  140M  313M  31% /boot
33G  2.7G   29G   9% /var
2.0G  443M  1.5G  24% /home
5.9G   65M  5.6G   2% /var/log
2.0G  3.0M  1.9G   1% /var/tmp
492M   35M  432M   8% /var/log/audit
100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1000
```

UPDATE :

df -i gives the following output :

```
262144 43638  218506   17% /
124118   378  123740    1% /dev
126926     1  126925    1% /dev/shm
126926   575  126351    1% /run
126926    16  126910    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
126926     9  126917    1% /tmp
6553600    11 6553589    1% /data
32768   344   32424    2% /boot
2162688 38203 2124485    2% /var
524288   869  523419    1% /home
393216    49  393167    1% /var/log
131072    13  131059    1% /var/tmp
131072    15  131057    1% /var/log/audit
126926     1  126925    1% /run/user/1000
```

Update : 
Ok my mistake. I read the output wrong. The var folder has ~40G and data folder has 94G space.

Comment: Learn to use the command line.

Comment: Yes, by mistake posted only half the question, please check updated one.

Comment: Which command have you shown the output? And what about `df -i`? and quotas? You need to edit even more your question

Comment: As mentioned the output is of df -h and the numbers dont add up to 100gb.

Comment: But you don't show the output of `df -i`. And your sysadmin might have enabled disk quotas.

Comment: Are you the sysadmin of that server? If yes, you should tell that (and probably ask on [unix & linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/))

Comment: oh I added the df -h output. Now updated the df -i ouput.

Comment: Show the `winscp` command, and explain in what Linux file system should the data go. We cannot guess that.

Comment: I am using winscp software to drag drop the tarball into the /home/ansible-user directory,

Comment: Avoid drag&drop. Prefer commands

Comment: I am on a windows machine trying to connect to the server. scp tarball.tar ansible-user@hostname:/home/ansible-user fails because of some proxy issues is my guess. I am able to configure the proxy in the software and then just upload the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use (on your remote Linux server, perhaps thru  `ssh`) both `df` and `df -i` to check the available space (both for data and for [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode)s). You might have no more inodes available, even if a lot of data space remains free. See [df(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/df.1.html). And there could be [disk quotas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_quota). See [quota(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/quota.1.html) and ask your sysadmin.

> error that no space left

That could be either data space, or inode space (or some disk quota exceeded). You should use *both* `df` and `df -i` to find out.

> How can I increase the space allocated to the home/ansible folder?

That is a question for the sysadmin of your Linux server (who probably is also in charge of installing software). BTW, Linux has [directories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(computing)), not folders (folders are visible in some GUI, and might not be shown).

The amount of space dedicated for inodes and for data is fixed when creating the [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) with [mkfs(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mkfs.8.html) (actually with [mke2fs(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mke2fs.8.html) for [ext4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) file systems); usually that is happening when installing your Linux distribution. You could consider resizing it, but be sure to backup all the data (on some external storage) before attempting (on some *unmounted* partition) any [resize2fs(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/resize2fs.8.html) (it is a risky operation, and you might lose all your disk partition if something goes wrong...)

At last, I recommend copying the `*tar.gz` archive to your remote Linux server, and use on that server some `tar xvf` command to extract it. Try `tar tvf` before. See [tar(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html).